# Modeling conditional relationships in neo4j v.2 (cypher)

Tags: neo4j, conditional-statements, cypher, relationships

I have two related problems I need help with.

Problem 1: How do I model a conditional relationship?
I want my data to indicate that when test CLT1's "Result" property = "High", CLT1 has relationship to Disease A. If I take a node-centric approach, I imagine that the code might look something like...

```
(CLT 1 {Result: "High"})  -[:INDICATES] -> (Disease A)
```

Further, when CLT1's "Result" property = "Low", CLT1 has a relationship to Disease B

```
(CLT 1 {Result: "Low"})  -[:INDICATES] ->  (Disease B)
```

Alternatively, if I take a relationship-centric approach, the code might look like this...

```
(CLT 1) -[:INDICATES {Result: "High"}] -> (Disease A)
(CLT 1) -[:INDICATES {Result: "Low"} ] -> (Disease B)
```

Problem 2

I have had the experience that I am modeling my data, there is 1 node with a unique name, but either different labels  or properties.  The thing is that I want these nodes to be distinguishable.  However, they are not as they look the same to cypher.

I can either give them multiple properties, labels or different names.  The diversity has to be for each different class... in labels or properties (1+n labels, properties) or in different names.

Problem 2 relates to Problem 1 in that I can't model the conditional relationship or distinguish the same node (CLT1) by its labels or properties.  I may have to resolve it by making the query-able "condition" in the relationship.

DO I have this right?  Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I'd take the relationship-centric approach as this kind of represents the inference of the information leading from your result-node to the disease.

Should work pretty well in modeling and querying too.

For your second question. That's what node-labels are for they represent different **roles** a node can play, each with **different relevant** properties and relationships.

So you could do `MATCH (p:Person {name:"Jose"})` and treat it differently from `MATCH (d:Developer {name:"Jose"})`. I.e look at other props and rels.

Comment: Hey Michael, Thanks for getting back.  OK, but the second problem is that CLT1 has Label A and Property B.  However, another variety of CLT1 has Label B and Property C. They are all CLT1, but if I try to define them with the same name, Neo4j/cypher says its already been defined based on the name.  It appears that I can only distinguish a node based on the name, not on the labels or properties.  So sort of combine name w/ property or label or give multiple properties and/or labels.  Those seem to be the options.

Comment: Michael, Upon considering your answer, I think I am having a fundamental misunderstanding.  I was thinking that the name of the node usually went first after the create statement ....(CREATE (Hugo:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving', born:1960})).  What I am thinking from what your answer is that I can put the pertinent labels first and leave the name as a property.  The fact that "Hugo" was used in the movies example is not necessarily the best practice. If you don't include the name, then you have more flexibility. Do I have this right?

Comment: Jose: now you have it right. The name you give a node in Cyber is just a variable name, and has no other meaning